# Étale cover of proper schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, grothendieck-topologies

In Topology, by Definition, when we have a compact space $X$ and an open cover $(U_i)_{i\in I}$, there exists a finite subcover $U_1,\ldots, U_n$ which covers $X$.

Is there an analogous definition for general Grothendieck topologies? For instance, does there exist the definition of properness in the étale topology, by which I mean that if $(U_i \rightarrow X)_i$ is an étale cover of $X$, there exists a finite subset of étale open $(U_1\rightarrow X), \ldots, (U_n \rightarrow X)$?

Furthermore, if $k$ is a field and $X$ a proper $k$-scheme, is it proper in the étale topology?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the general statement, it sounds like what you are looking for is a [coherent topos](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/coherent+topos). I'm not an expert on this, so there may be better terminology suggestions or references from people who are.

For the specific question of when an etale covering of a scheme has a finite subcover, it suffices for $X$ to be quasicompact. SGA4, section VIII (available [here](http://library.msri.org/books/sga/sga/pdf/sga4-2.pdf) at MSRI's website) or [Stacks 021E](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/021E) explains that the etale topos is equivalent to the topos of sheaves on the site obtained from the full subcategory of affine finitely presented etale schemes over $X$. As every affine morphism is quasicompact, we see that each such cover has a finite subcover.

For the more specific case of $X$ proper over a field, since proper morphisms are universally closed and universally closed morphisms are quasicompact, we see that the previous paragraph applies and any etale covering should have a finite subcover.

Comment: In your second paragraph, I think you need that $X$ is also quasi-separated to have the equivalence you claim (SGA 4, VII, 3.1 & 3.2).

Comment: This restriction can be removed - the equivalence between the relevant topoi is completely general for all schemes, as proven in [Stacks 021E](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/021E). If I have the time later, I'll try and find an explanation from SGA, but I make no guarantees (I am fairly slow at reading French).